# How do I detect the collision of two sprites using pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision

This is my code so far, I can move and it places out a blip to pick up, I just need to know how to register that and move the blip to a new random spot!
I am very new to pygame and not 100% fluent in python either, but I'm decent. If there are pdf:s good for intermediate coders when it comes to python that would be wonderful!

```
import sys, pygame, os, math
from random import randint

pygame.init()

size = width, height = 800, 600
speed = [2, 2]
black = 1, 1, 1
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption('Pick up the squares!')
UP='up'
DOWN='down'
LEFT='left'
RIGHT='right'

ball = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
ballrect = ball.get_rect()
ballx = 400
bally = 300

blip = pygame.image.load("blip.png")
bliprect = blip.get_rect()
blipx = randint(1,800)
blipy = randint(1,600)

background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()

background.fill((250, 250, 250))


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        ballx  -= 5
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        ballx += 5
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        bally -= 5
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        bally +=5    

    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(ball, (ballx,bally))
    screen.blit(blip, (blipx, blipy))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(40)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `colliderect` method of rectangles:

```
if ballrect.colliderect(bliprect):
    print 'Do something here'
```

Comment: Can I use it to say 'if ballrect.colliderec(bliprect):  to then change position of the blip to a new one?

Comment: Yeah, isn't that the point? Under the if statement, simply set the position of the rectangle you wish to change. Please mark as answer if you can.

Answer (score 0):

A basic collision detection works like this (assuming you are working with two rectangles):

```
def does_collide(rect1, rect2):
    if rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width and rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x \ 
       and rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height and rect1.height + rect1.y > rect2.y:
        return True
    return False
```

Fortunately Pygame is packed with such methods, so you should go with @MalikBrahimi's answer - using `colliderect` function call, which will do the math for you.

Comment: Hey again domi. There's no need to test coordinates when there are predefined methods to do the work for you.

Comment: Evening Malik, it is good to understand the math behind the collision which a true game developer should know! :)

Comment: Here's an [article](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/11/26/GameDev-math-recipes-Collision-detection-using-an-axis-aligned-bounding-box.aspx) of relevance that can thoroughly explain the theory.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try using `pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`:

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(a, b, False):
    pass
    #Do something
```

`a` here is your variable name for the class for one of the sprites in the collision. `b` here is the *group* that your second sprite will be. You can set the last one to True, which will remove the sprite from the *group*. Setting to False will keep it the way it is. Here is an example:

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(my_ball, ballGroup, False):
    Ball.speed[0] = -Ball.speed[0]
    hit.play()
Ball.move()
```

The variable name for my sprite is `my_ball`. The group containing the other sprite(s) in this collision is `ballGroup`. I set the last one to False to keep all the sprites on the surface. If I set to True, the sprite from `ballGroup` will be removed from the group and screen. I hope this helps you!